# Lasso regression glmnet assigning Y value.

Tags: r, regression, glmnet, lasso-regression

Okay so I'm doing a LASSO regression but I'm having problems with my Y term. 
I know my X has to be a matrix and the y's have to be numeric. 
This is the case in my set. However I feel my model does not run properly. I first show you what I did and then what I think should be done (but no idea how to do it).

So what I did is as follows. I used the nuclear dataset from R for this example.

```
library(boot)
data("nuclear")
attach(nuclear)
nuclear <- as.matrix(nuclear)
```

So I converted it to a matrix. And then I used my matrix on x and y.

```
CV = cv.glmnet(x=nuclear,y=nuclear, family="multinomial", type.measure = "class", alpha = 1, nlambda = 100)
```

However i feel my Y-axis is not correct. I feel somehow my dependent variable should be there. But how do I get it there? Assume that nuclear$pt is my dependent variable. Putting nuclear$pt for Y does not work.

```
plot(CV)

fit = glmnet(x=nuclear, y=nuclear, family = "multinomial" , alpha=1, lambda=CV$lambda.1se)
```

If i then run this it feels my model didn't run at all. Probably something miss with my Y but i can't put my finger on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You used the same matrix for x and y. You have to separate the independent and dependent variables somehow. For example, you can use indices to select the variables:

```
cv.glmnet(x=nuclear[, 1:10],y=nuclear[, 11], family="binomial", 
   type.measure = "class", alpha = 1, nlambda = 100)
```

This will use the first 10 columns of nuclear as independent variables and the 11th column as dependent variable.

Comment: It works, thank you so much. Now I'll be trying to do the same with my real model. I'll let you know how it went.

Comment: Hmm in my own model I get the error;

"Error in cbind2(1, newx) %*% nbeta : invalid class 'NA' to dup_mMatrix_as_dgeMatrix

I know you helped me a lot already and it doesn't really belong to this specific example, but any idea how to fix this?

Comment: @Thundersheep no idea. You should probably ask that as a new question but only if you can make that reproducible.

Comment: yeah that's the thing i cannot make that reproduceable unfortunately. Guess i have to figure it out myself then. thanks for the help though.

Comment: @Thundersheep it looks like you have some NAs in there which should not be there ("invalid class NA") but that's for you to figure out.

Comment: I just figured that out yes. I deleted them but as soon as I create a matrix they come back! So it's not working for now. I'll see if i can make some re-produceable example later this weekend.

Comment: I also wonder if you can apply this to a normal linear model. what family type should i then use?

Comment: Never mind it was a typo, i fixed it, thanks all to you.